# backboneJS render view issue with a collection: only first added element is displayed

Tags: backbone.js

i'm using backboneJS with requireJS and jQueryMobile.

everything is doing well for all my views/collection, except for one collection that is not triggering render method on each add, but only the first.

here's the code:

HTML:

```
        <div data-role="page" id="board">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>My Notes </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul id="listOfNotes" data-role="listview">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
var NoteModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(attributes, options)
    {
        this.set({
            "id": attributes["id"] ? attributes["id"] : "",
            "label": attributes["label"] ? attributes["label"] : "",
            "text": attributes["text"] ? attributes["text"] : "",
            "size" : attributes["size"] ? attributes["size"] : ""
        });
    },

});

var NotesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend( {

    model: NoteModel
});

// Extends Backbone.View
var BoardDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    /**
     * The View Constructor
     * @param el, DOM element of the page
     */
    initialize: function(options) 
    {
         this.collection.on("add", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty(); // clear the element to make sure you don't double
        var self = this; // so you can use this inside the each function
        this.collection.each(function(noteModel){
            console.log('render note : ' + noteModel);
            var id = noteModel.get("id");
            var text = noteModel.get("text");
            var li = "<li><a href=\"#note/"+id+"\">"+text+"</a></li>";
            self.$el.append(li);
        });
        self.$el.listview().listview("refresh", true);

        return this;
    },
    /**
     * clear the view manually
     */
    empty: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
    }

});


var note1 = new NoteModel({'noteId':'1', 'text':'label 1'});
var note2 = new NoteModel({'noteId':'2', 'text':'label 2'});
var note3 = new NoteModel({'noteId':'3', 'text':'label 3'});
window.app.boardDetailsView = new BoardDetailsView({el: '#listOfNotes', collection: new NotesCollection()});
window.app.boardDetailsView.collection.add(note1);
window.app.boardDetailsView.collection.add(note2);
window.app.boardDetailsView.collection.add(note3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all your notes are being assigned the same id (actually a blank string, which is probably not a good idea by itself) since you are checking for the *id* attribute but passing in a *noteId* attribute.

```
var NoteModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(attributes, options)
    {
        this.set({
            "id": attributes["noteId"] ? attributes["noteId"] : "",
            "label": attributes["label"] ? attributes["label"] : "",
            "text": attributes["text"] ? attributes["text"] : "",
            "size" : attributes["size"] ? attributes["size"] : ""
        });
    } 

});
```

Here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jegezule/1/)